# WEKA and Scikit-Learn Multilayer Perceptron Gives Different Result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, weka

everyone

I'm currently running a research using Multilayer perceptron.
I previously run this using WEKA but I have migrated to scikit-learn in python for various reason.

I tried to reproduce my prediction results in WEKA to scikit-learn so I made an exact perceptron with the exact same learning rate, momentum, hidden layer, etc
However, the prediction results turns out differently for these both platforms. Can anybody gives me some explanation regarding this matter?

The only thing that I notice is that scikit learn uses either lbfgs, adam, and sgd to optimize its connection weight while WEKA uses backpropagation. But could it be the only reason? or is there another reason?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you train a neural net with a different optimizer, it will certainly give different results. This difference could be slight or tremendous. All NN optimization algorithms use backpropagation - i.e., LBFGS, Adam, and SGD all use backpropagation. Also - in general - training the same NN twice will likely never give you the *exact* same result - this is because most optimizers (at least the ones worth your time) take partially stochastic steps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer:
With what you said regarding everything uses backpropagation, it makes me realize that I don't know for sure what kind of optimizer that WEKA actually use. I know that it uses gradient descent. I just don't know what kind of gradient descent that it uses. Is it the same with SGD or does it have some kind of difference that might affect my prediction result is still beyond my knowledge at this moment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WEKA, and a skim of the docs wasn't too helpful - if you are unable to select an optimization algorithm, it is likely not a very good platform for deep learning. NNs are great because they can model any function, but they are also very difficult to train. I would recommend you use PyTorch or TensorFlow to get more flexibility (and support!).